# Translation of database with poedit and zend translate

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-translate, poedit

Poedit does not automatically recognise the content of a table in a database.
What is the best way to get the content of a table recognized by poedit for its translation in zend. I would like it to be done automatically....do I have to create an xml file from the database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not translate database contents with poedit. You would do that inside the database. The short answer: what you want cannot be achieved, unfortunately.

You can translate "fixed" strings and if you want to get variables, constant or database values translated, you have to do that via literal string translations, in the case poedit has to scan them:

```
<?php
if($var === 'foo') {
    echo $this->translate('foo');
} else {
    echo $this->translate('bar');
}
```

It's easier if you have a 1:n relation with a `Translation` object. The view would then pull the translation from user generated content:

```
<?php
echo $foo->Translation['en-us']->bar;
```

An example of this last possibility is provided in the Gedmo doctrine extension: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md