# Translate database content with Poedit

Tags: python, flask, poedit

I'm developint a Flask-WebApp and I'd like to internationalize it. I'm following the Flask-Babel API but then I faced a problem, the translation with PoEdit.

Do I need to translate every entry I flag as **to-translate** manually? What if I want to translate content from the database? Such as comments or new posts? How do I maintain it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Translating database content with poedit is not the way to go about this as database content is dynamic and babel translations are static. 
The right approach would be creating a translation table (1:n relation object), and fetching transations.

Here is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497489/translating-strings-from-database-flask-babel) that might help, [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619356/translation-of-database-with-poedit-and-zend-translate)